# Add dolist variables to a list in LISP

Tags: list, loops, variables, lisp

I have two dolists. The first dolist has a variable i and the inner dolist has a variable j.
I want to make a final list li look like ((00)(01)(10)(11))

```
(setq mm '(0 1))
(setq li '())
(dolist (i mm)
  (dolist (j mm)
    (progn
      (setq ans (cons ans (list (nth i mm)
                                (nth j mm)))))))
```

gives me
((((NIL 0 0) 0 1) 1 0) 1 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CL-USER 68 > (let ((ans ()))
               (dolist (i mm (reverse ans))
                 (dolist (j mm)
                   (setq ans (cons (list (nth i mm)
                                         (nth j mm))
                                   ans)))))
((0 0) (0 1) (1 0) (1 1))
```

Comment: Thank you :).
Also, for larger number values in ans, I am not able to see the whole list of ans when I type ans.
How can I increase the buffer to see all whole list.
I am using LISP personal works.
Thank you again.

Answer (score -1):

Got it.
The keyword "List" does the trick.
    (dolist (i mm) (dolist(j mm) (progn (setq ans (append ans (list(list(nth i mm   )(nth j mm))))))))

Comment: This is very inefficient, since `(append ans ...)` *copies* `ans`.  Instead of doing a small operation on each iteration, this does a bigger and bigger operation every time.  Code formatting in answers is appreciated, too.  But I'm glad that you found a solution, and thank you for posting it!